# how find radio button value

Tags: javascript

i have a four radio buttons in a row.
so i have 10 rows in a table. all radio buttons in a row having same id.
in one time, only one radio button in a row can be selected.
some radio buttons are checked and some non checked.
i want to put a validation when submit the form. when i submit the form if all radio button is non selected in a row then a msg box can be appear.
i have found the radio button id but i am not able to get their value, either true or false.
it show me in a alert box: `radiobutton Value is: undefined`

here is the method:

```
function showValue() {
var  radioID="radiobutton";
var radiobuttonName;
var radiobuttonValue;
   for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
  radiobuttonName=radioID+i;
  alert("radiobutton Name is:"+radiobuttonName);
  if (radiobuttonName.checked)
  {
      radiobuttonValue=radiobuttonName.value
  }
 alert("radiobutton Value is:"+radiobuttonValue);
    }
}
```

> Edit:

i have four radio button in a row.
name and id is same of all four button in a row.
suppose, name and id for all buttons in first row is radiobutton0. for second row it is radiobutton1, for third row it is radiobutton2. thus i have 10 rows in a table.
my aim is  when i submit the page, one button must be checked in a row else it show a msg box that please fill the corresponding radio button. .
i want to get the value of radio button either true or false.

i run the following code:`function get_radio_value()
{
    var  radioID="radiobutton";
var radiobuttonName;
var radiobuttonValue;
   for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
  radiobuttonName=radioID+i;
  alert("radiobutton Name is:"+:"+radiobuttonName);
}
}`

 this method execute the loop and display all radiobutton Names.
How i find radiobuttonValue which is either true or false.

Comment: radiobuttonName is a string, so radiobuttonName.checked is not a valid statement.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to alert the `.value` property of a string (`radiobuttonName` is just a string, not an element), which is undefined, instead you need something like this:

```
function showValue() {
  var radioID="radiobutton", radiobuttonName, radiobuttonValue, rb;
   for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
     radiobuttonName=radioID+i;
     rb = document.getElementsByName(radiobuttonName)[0];
     alert("radiobutton Name is:"+radiobuttonName);
     if (rb.checked)
     {
        radiobuttonValue=rb.value
     }
     alert("radiobutton Value is:"+radiobuttonValue);
   }
}
```

In the above we're getting the first element with that name (I'm guessing by your naming conventions), if it had an ID for example, you'd replace `document.getElementsByName(radiobuttonName)[0]` with `document.getElementById(radiobuttonName)`.

Comment: now it is not show alert box of radiobutton Value. how i get their value, either true or false.

Comment: @user531348 - it'll only show it if it's checked, is that the case?  It seems like you'd want to move that `alert()` *inside* the `if()` statement

Comment: Nick, i run your method but it show only radiobutton Name and show only for one time...please review the query.